# Java method which uses a file system hierarchy to create a tree

Tags: java, arrays, string, tree, apache-zookeeper

I'm facing the following issue and I've been racking my brain looking for a solution, but nothing comes to my mind by now:

I have a file system hierarchy, something like:

```
/HANDLERS/HANDLER1
/HANDLERS/HANDLER2
/HANDLERS/HANDLER3
```

and

```
/MODULES/PROGRAMMING/PROGRAMMER1
/MODULES/PROGRAMMING/PROGRAMMER2
/MODULES/PROGRAMMING/PROGRAMMER3

/MODULES/TESTING/TESTING1
/MODULES/TESTING/TESTING2
```

and so on.

I want to create a "tree" assuming "/" which is the root is already created. And the structure shown in the image I attach is the goal.

[image]

I need a method called

```
void createNode(String path){

}
```

In my requirements, this method will always receive the full path and do something like the following:

```
void create(String fullPath){
 //Here I use a method which splits the fullPath into a String array to get every part that will represent a node, for example, if the fullPath is /MODULE/PROGRAMMING/PROHRAMMER1 I use:
String[] singleNodes = separateNodes(fullPath);//I get:MODULE,PROGRAMMING AND PROGRAMMER
//Then I use a loop to iterate the elements

for (String s : singleNodes) {
}
//WHAT CAN I DO HERE?
}
```

But I don't have idea on how to work inside the loop, I need to check if the node exists, if it exists, I just have to add the missing part, for instance, if I send /MODULES/PROGRAMMING/PROGRAMMER1, if I send for the very first time, it will create the whole thing, but if then I send /MODULES/PROGRAMMING/PROGRAMMER2, it just have to add PROGRAMMER2.

If somebody could help me I will really appretiate it, thanks in advance.

Comment: You have the logic, just put it into code.

Comment: There are numerous scripts around for generating `hierarchy trees` or [`family trees`](http://www.familytreephp.com/introduction/). I think you'd be best off using one of these scripts, why reinvent the wheel, right?

Comment: I know that there are many scripts, but I'm facing an issue related with zookeeper, which is strict with nodes and trees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it finally and it fits my requirements, it is related to a question I asked for zookeeper.

Best regards.

```
public void createNode(NodePath nodePath, NodeData nodeData, NodeRights nodeRights, NodeCreationHandler nodeCreationHandler) throws KeeperException, InterruptedException, ZookeeperCreationException {

        if (zk == null) {
            throw new ZookeeperCreationException("The zookeeper client has not been instanced.");
        }       
        String targetPath = nodePath.getFullNodePath();
        logger.warn("full path: " + targetPath);
        targetPath = targetPath.substring(1, targetPath.length());
        logger.warn("full path mod: " + targetPath);
        byte[] serializedData = nodeData.serialize(new Object());
        String[] array = targetPath.split(ICoordinationConstants.BASE_ROOT_SPTR);
        String acum="";
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++) {
            acum+=(ICoordinationConstants.BASE_ROOT_SPTR+array[i]);
            logger.warn("acum: " + acum);
            if (zk.exists(acum, null) == null) {
                logger.warn("It does not exists, proceed to create it...");
                zk.create(acum, serializedData, Ids.OPEN_ACL_UNSAFE, CreateMode.PERSISTENT);
            }
        }
        zk.create(acum+ICoordinationConstants.BASE_ROOT_SPTR+array[array.length-1], serializedData, Ids.OPEN_ACL_UNSAFE, CreateMode.EPHEMERAL);             
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**How to convert a filepath into a hierarchy in Java**

```
Node createNode(String path) {
    File location = new File(path);
    File[] children = file.listFiles();
    Node node = new Node(location.getName());

    if(location.isDirectory()) {
        List<Node> children = new ArrayList();
        for(File child : children) {
            children.add(createNode(child.getPath()));
        }
        node.setChildren(children);
    }
    return node;
}

class Node {
    String name;
    List<Node> children;
}
```

You could call this by `createNode(myRoot)`

Comment: pretty cool code, but, actually it does not fits what I want to do, I keep on working in the logic. Thanks anyway, this can help me a clue on how to work the new logic I'm implementing.

Comment: What are you looking for? A way to directly display this hierarchy?

Comment: I was looking for a way just to create the tree structure, it does not matter if works with files or not, I was just focusing on how can I implement the structure of the tree with the validations I mentioned in the question.

Comment: Well, depends...what's your frontend? A website or a desktop application or an android app or...

Answer (score 1):

**disclaimer:** not tested, no error checking, no getters/setters.

```
package com.jorge.teste;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static class Tree<T> {
        Node<T> root;

        public static class Node<T> {
            T data;

            Node<T> parent;

            List<Node<T>> children = new ArrayList<Main.Tree.Node<T>>();

            public Node(final T data, final Node<T> parent) {
                this.data = data;
                this.parent = parent;
            }
        }
    }

    public static Tree<String> tree = new Tree<String>();

    public static void createNode(final String path) {
        String[] parts = path.split("/");
        Tree.Node<String> parent = null;
        for (String part : parts) {
            if (parent == null) {
                if (tree.root == null) {
                    tree.root = new Tree.Node<String>(part, null);
                }
                parent = tree.root;
            } else {
                Tree.Node<String> found = null;
                for (Tree.Node<String> child : parent.children) {
                    if (child.data.equals(part)) {
                        found = child;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (found == null) {
                    parent.children.add(found = new Tree.Node<String>(part, parent));
                }

                parent = found;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        createNode("/a/b/c");
        createNode("/a/b/c/d");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with the loop you have currently then you should try something like this 
(i am assuming you already have the root node as you stated above)

```
Node currentNode = rootNode; 
for (String s : singleNodes) {
     if( currentNode.hasChild(s) ) currentNode = currentNode.getChild(s);
     else currentNode = currentNode.createChild(s);
}
```

assuming here that createChild(s) returns the created Node which maybe it shouldn't. but that's not really the problem

but in all honesty I dont think this should be done using a loop, Trees are usually better handled using recursion.